# How to run celery on windows?

Tags: python, celery

How to run celery worker on Windows without creating Windows Service? Is there any analogy to `$ celery -A your_application worker`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's done the same way as in Linux. Changing directory to module containing celery task and calling `"c:\python\python" -m celery -A module.celery worker` worked well.

Comment: There are typos you need to fix. More so, you don't need to call `python` before using celery. Doing `celery -A tasks worker -l info` should be sufficient if you have your `PYTHONPATH`correctly set.

Comment: what typos do you mean?

Comment: pyton (`python`), woker (`worker`). I just thought it would better serve those who will have the same question

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Isn't `PYTHONPATH` just for the `import` statements? How could the Celery binary be found without having `Python\Scripts` directory in `PATH` or calling `python -m`?

Answer (score 76):

`Celery 4.0+` does not officially support window already. But it still works on window for some development/test purpose.

Use `eventlet` instead as below:

```
pip install eventlet
celery -A <module> worker -l info -P eventlet
```

It works for me on `window 10` + `celery 4.1` + `python 3`.

[This solution](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4081) solved the following exception:

```
[2017-11-16 21:19:46,938: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: ValueError('need more than 0 values to unpack',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\wchen8\work\venv\weinsta\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 358, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\wchen8\work\venv\weinsta\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 525, in _fast_trace_task
    tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

===== update 2018-11 =====

Eventlet has an issue on subprocess.CalledProcessError:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4063

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/357

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/413

So try `gevent` instead.

```
pip install gevent
celery -A <module> worker -l info -P gevent
```

This works for me on `window 10` + `celery 4.2` + `python 3.6`

Comment: this also works with gevent and solo concurrency pool implementations (tested with Windows 10 and Celery 4.2.1): See https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/celery-4-windows for example code

Comment: nice! works (sort of) under windows server 12, python 3.7.1, celery 4.2.1, gevent 1.3.7.  The only issue for me is monitoring of these workers. `celery *** inspect active` works initially after workers are turned on, and then after about 5 minutes it becomes unresponsive, not sure why yet (this was not an issue under python 3.3.5, celery 4.1.0 eventlet 0.22.1).

Comment: for future readers, the issue that I am encountering is discussed here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4817 seems like the work around is setting `CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 0`.

Comment: Does this work for concurrent requests scenario to celery worker?

Answer (score 29):

yes:

```
celery -A your_application -l info
```

also note Celery have [dropped support for Windows(since v4)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#removed-features), so best to

```
pip install celery==3.1.25
```

[3.1.25 was the last version](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/index.html) that works on windows(just tested on my win10 machine). Didn't need to downgrade flower(browser monitor for celery) though.

See also the [FAQ for Windows](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=Windows#windows)

Comment: the link goes to a non existent page.

Comment: using 3.1.25  i got ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Comment: It works for celery version 4.0 and above as well for windows OS, you just have to enable multiprocessing environment variable before creating celery instance.

Comment: Cannot install version 3.1.25, gives an error: `error in anyjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.` during installation

Answer (score 20):

Compile Celery with **--pool=solo** argument.

Example:
`celery -A your-application worker -l info --pool=solo`

Comment: Can you please explain why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 8):

There are two workarounds to make Celery 4 work on Windows:

- use eventlet, gevent or solo concurrency pool (if your tasks as I/O and not CPU-bound)
- set the environment variable FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING=1 (this is what actually causes the underlying billiard package to to fail under Windows since version 4)

See https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows for more details

---

Comment: What are the ramifications for selecting the second option? I still can't successfully `revoke()` a task after its been executed...

Answer (score 8):

I have run celery task using RabbitMQ server.
RabbitMq is better and simple than redis broker

while running celery use this command "celery -A project-name worker --pool=solo -l info"
and avoid this command "celery -A project-name worker --loglevel info"

Comment: For -P solo option, if the task takes longer time like around 2 hours, connection reset error will occur on windows.

Answer (score 7):

Celery 4.0+ does not officially support window already. But it still works on window for some development/test purpose.
you can use any of this:

```
celery worker --app=app.app --pool=eventlet --loglevel=INFO

celery worker --app=app.app --pool=gevent --loglevel=INFO

celery worker --app=app.app --pool=solo --loglevel=INFO
```

or using other format:

```
celery -A <app> worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet

celery -A <app> worker --loglevel=info -P gevent 

celery -A <app> worker --loglevel=info -P solo
```

if you have get `context` error then upgrade gevent 20.6.2 and eventlet to  0.26.1 or use `solo`

https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/

Comment: if multiprocessing environment variable is enabled, no need to specify pool to eventlet or gevent or solo. It will work with default pool on windows as well for celery version 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 6):

You can run celery on windows without an extra library by using threads

`celery -A your_application worker -P threads`

Comment: This disables multiple processes. All workers would run within the same process. It is good if you want a quick bit of concurrency but your tasks would hinder eachother if they require a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use celery 4 0+ with Windows 10+
Just use this command "celery -A projet worker - -pool=solo - l info" instead of "celery - A project worker -l info

Comment: For -P solo option, if the task takes longer time like around 2 hours, connection reset error will occur on windows

Answer (score 2):

After feeling like killing myself by using celery 4.4 on windows, I think I can answer this question.

For celery version 4.0 and above, first set following environment variable in python code before creation of celery instance.

```
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')
```

Then run celery worker command with default pool option.

```
celery worker -A <celery_file> -l info
```

This will run celery worker concurrently with multiple child processes.

**Note**: When you run celery with **gevent** or **eventlet** pool, it will work but it won't run concurrent processes on windows.

Comment: What are the ramifications for selecting the second option? I still can't successfully `revoke()` a task after its been executed...

Answer (score 0):

To run celery on windows for development. you have two methods.

1. **Use Windows as Host Machine.**

- Install Redis Server from https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads
- Run redis_server.exe
- Install Celery using `Pip install Celery`.
- Run Celery commands.

**Limitations:**

- This method is only supported for Python 3.6 or lower.
- Celery 4 does not provide support for windows.
- will be using Old Redis-server Version.
- Hard to manage

**4. Using WSL for running Celery and Redis-server**

- Install WSL using this guide https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10.
- Install redis-server using `sudo apt install redis-server` on the WSL terminal.
- Install Celery and Execute all celery-related commands on WSL.

WSL would be a friend for you on windows if you have already familiar with Linux.
With few limitations including support of Docker on WSL. you can perform most of the Development tasks using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Celery is testing it with windows in it's CI again from version 5.x and you can try using it with windows if any issue occurs try set following environment variable in python code before creation of celery instance

```
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')
```

But as far as I know celery now officially support running on windows for development purpose.

Comment: How is this answer different than this one, where this suggestion was already made?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944021/3250829

Comment: that doesn't mention that celery restarted support for windows again in v5 but I can edit my post

Answer (score -2):

I've made a .bat file besides my manage.py file with this code:

```
title CeleryTask
::See the title at the top.
cd 
cmd /k celery -A MainProject worker -l info
```

so each time I want to run celery, I just double-click this batch file and it runs perfectly.
And the fact that you can't use celery 4 on windows is true.

Comment: you can use celery 4 on windows:
celery -A MainProject worker -l info - -pool=solo

Comment: @rogers.wang, -P solo also has issues. When you run long running task for around 2 hours, connection reset error will occur between celery worker and client