# task receive but doesn't excute

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm learning Django. recently I tried to use celery. the problem that I'm facing with it is tasks are receiving but they don't execute.

settings.py:

```
# Celery application definition
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')
app = Celery('myshop')
app.config_from_object('django.conf.settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import task, shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order

import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@shared_task()
def order_created(order_id):
    logger.error('msg received')
    """
    Task to send an e-mail notification when an order is
    successfully created.
    """

    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)

    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = f'Order nr. {order.id}'
    message = f'Dear {order.first_name},\n\n' \
              f'You have successfully placed an order.' \
              f'Your order ID is {order.id}.'
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          'admin@myshop.com',
                          [order.email])
    logger.error('mail sent')
    return mail_sent
```

running task in views.py:

```
# launch asynchronous task
            logger.error('before task')
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            logger.error('after task')
```

cmd log after running celery with `celery -A myshop worker -l info`:

```
(venv) E:\Workspace\django-shop\myshop>celery -A myshop worker -l info

 -------------- celery@DESKTOP-F7E0RGJ v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-06-23 03:37:15
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myshop:0x4b93df0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . myshop.celery.debug_task
  . orders.tasks.order_created

[2020-06-23 03:37:15,800: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2020-06-23 03:37:15,823: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,320: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 15856 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,328: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 13464 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,332: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 13528 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,337: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 4660 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,344: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 9040 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,346: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 17044 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,358: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 16480 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,366: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 16876 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,885: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,913: WARNING/MainProcess] e:\workspace\django-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:202: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,914: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-F7E0RGJ ready.
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,918: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[1d366fb3-262b-4d28-92ab-8a7b85f1deff]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,921: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[a1d79ddb-eb2f-4791-9e8a-f1a71bf5f44e]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,924: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[afb84e39-3d10-42d0-ab9e-333917ff66f9]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,927: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[86dc7ad7-66e6-4f3a-9db1-6f2a5cb5791f]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,931: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: myshop.celery.debug_task[8169ff3e-ceae-478f-87ab-4020bedb8338]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,935: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[e689b21e-78b6-498b-adb4-f64dedbbbac8]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,938: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[92db7aa9-bf16-4be1-9769-a1986ffc6f6d]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,940: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[5c0e9873-2671-49a6-9c53-db6dfdd041ef]
[2020-06-23 03:37:16,943: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[8d17faa5-19d7-49ed-8181-5a334423c1bb]
[2020-06-23 03:37:18,420: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[4671d8c9-11dd-4c9a-a7b1-d0cfedab5e0a]
[2020-06-23 03:37:18,443: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[c8f588c4-6e21-4fc8-b441-b65456207cd6]
[2020-06-23 03:37:18,453: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[509fd1ad-eac9-4aab-b1f1-1c6278ebbffc]
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,080: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 10652 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,095: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 13548 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,097: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 252 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,112: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 4604 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,119: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 12696 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,121: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 13080 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,125: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 12420 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:19,159: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 4468 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:21,177: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-20] child process 14032 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:21,183: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-19] child process 11220 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:21,183: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-18] child process 1084 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:37:21,191: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-17] child process 14020 calling self.run()
```

and log after create a new task:

```
[2020-06-23 03:41:32,735: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.tasks.order_created[758b7636-314b-40df-8458-d03bb1ca2ac2]
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,536: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-22] child process 16052 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,537: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-21] child process 9664 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,538: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-24] child process 18172 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,546: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-26] child process 9704 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,547: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-23] child process 10612 calling self.run()
[2020-06-23 03:41:33,547: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-25] child process 11176 calling self.run()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the logs I assume you are on Windows. However, since Celery 4.x [Windows is no longer supported](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows). Problems you are encountering are also described in this [Celery issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5738) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows). The general discussion about running Celery 4.x on Windows can be found [here](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/). The solution to your problem seems to be to use e.g. gevent execution pool (more on execution pools can be found [here](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/)). When using Django:

```
python manage.py celery worker -P gevent
```

Comment: For anyone on windows this^ worked for me, also see here issues here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4081#issuecomment-338566864
solution I used was to use eventlet  `python manage.py celery worker -P eventlet`

Answer (score 11):

Windows does not support celery 4.0+,
So To Solve this issue :-

1. We have to install gevent using pip :-

   pip install gevent
2. Then to run celery,

   celery -A <proj_name> worker -l info -P gevent

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. I think window doesn't allow celery to run multiple threads or workers. I always run with pool = solo. I had the problem when I forgot to do that.

Run this:

celery -A eazzier worker -l info --pool=solo

Instead of:
celery -A eazzier worker --loglevel=info

Answer (score 0):

In  hope that this will help someone I also faced this problem, I use Django in its most recent version as well as Celery.
In fact since version 4 of celery Windows is not supported to get around this problem you need another library like Gevent more information [on this page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is surely due to OS Environment:
For widows to run celery worker use:
celery -A YOURPROJECTNAME.celery worker --pool=solo -l info

Comment: celery -A myCeleryProject.celery worker --pool=solo -l info --> returned in line as per execution order
            AND
celery -A myCeleryProject.celery worker -l info -P gevent --> first completed will returned first