# Official celery project for django is not working

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using the official celery project for django, but it is not working on my machine.

I have installed all the necessary modules, and am using the example given in the link: [Example Django project using Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django).

I have already searched for the same error and used some solutions, but no solution fixed my problem. When I use the command: **celery -A proj worker -l INFO**, I get this response:

````
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0 2022-05-16 14:19:39
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x230fa67a6a0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . demoapp.tasks.add
  . demoapp.tasks.count_widgets
  . demoapp.tasks.mul
  . demoapp.tasks.rename_widget
  . demoapp.tasks.xsum
  . proj.celery.debug_task

[2022-05-16 14:19:40,464: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 7240 calling self.run()
[2022-05-16 14:19:40,481: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 6960 calling self.run()
[2022-05-16 14:19:40,493: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 10964 calling self.run()
[2022-05-16 14:19:40,516: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 6272 calling self.run()
[2022-05-16 14:19:41,978: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061]```

As I said I am using the source code itself, can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery [doesn't support Windows](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows).

But you can use eventlet to run it on Win, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows)

Also, make sure, that you have installed [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html) locally and it's running in port 5672. Also, you need to specify credentials for amqp server in `settings.py`

From your guide

> The settings file assumes that rabbitmq-server is running on localhost using the default ports.

Also, you can run amqp server as docker container. It could be easier option than installing it locally:

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```