# Can I setup a simple job queue with celery on a plotly dashboard?

Tags: python, plotly, celery, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a dashboard very similar to this one-

```
import datetime
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# pip install pyorbital
from pyorbital.orbital import Orbital
satellite = Orbital('TERRA')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)


# Multiple components can update everytime interval gets fired.
@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('live-update-graph', 'relayout'),
              Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph_live(relayout, n):
    if ctx.triggered_id == 'relayout':
        * code that affects the y axis * 
        return fig 
    else:
        satellite = Orbital('TERRA')
        data = {
            'time': [],
            'Latitude': [],
            'Longitude': [],
            'Altitude': []
        }

        # Collect some data
        for i in range(180):
            time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*20)
            lon, lat, alt = satellite.get_lonlatalt(
                time
            )
            data['Longitude'].append(lon)
            data['Latitude'].append(lat)
            data['Altitude'].append(alt)
            data['time'].append(time)

        # Create the graph with subplots
        fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.2)
        fig['layout']['margin'] = {
            'l': 30, 'r': 10, 'b': 30, 't': 10
        }
        fig['layout']['legend'] = {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'xanchor': 'left'}

        fig.append_trace({
            'x': data['time'],
            'y': data['Altitude'],
            'name': 'Altitude',
            'mode': 'lines+markers',
            'type': 'scatter'
        }, 1, 1)
        fig.append_trace({
            'x': data['Longitude'],
            'y': data['Latitude'],
            'text': data['time'],
            'name': 'Longitude vs Latitude',
            'mode': 'lines+markers',
            'type': 'scatter'
        }, 2, 1)

        return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I want to setup a job queue. Right now, the "code that affects the y axis" part never runs because the interval component fires before it finishes processing. I want to setup logic that says "add every callback to a queue and then fire them one at a time in the order that they were called".

Two questions

1- Can I achieve this with celery?

2- If so, what does a small working example look like?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901101/pythoncelery-chaining-jobs

Comment: Can you post an example with dash?